I have a table that consists of ad information like business name, start date etc. I need to work out expiry dates based on packages selected
I have created a statement with case which tells me how many days the ad has left before it expires based on the package that was selected. The problem is that it does not show expired when it reaches 0 days and the following day it starts adding a negative value -1 then -2 etc. I need some assistance in resolving the problem.
this is my query. NB I have no expiry column in my database
select business,whendt as 'start date', 
CASE 
 WHEN package = 'Monthly R100' AND whendt > 0 then datediff(whendt,CURDATE()- INTERVAL 30 day) 
 WHEN package = 'Biannual R500' AND whendt > 0 then datediff(whendt,CURDATE()- INTERVAL 180 day) 
 WHEN package = 'Yearly R1000' AND whendt > 0 then datediff(whendt,CURDATE()- INTERVAL 365 day) 
ELSE 'Expired' 
END as Remaining_days_to_expire 
from directory 


'I need some assistance in resolving the problem.' - What problem? What do you want when 0 or -ve? please add sample data and desired outcome.

I would guess that whendt never reaches 0. But you need to show us sample data, expected oitcome and the outcome your current query produces.

When it reaches 0 days i would like it to show the words expired and not continue to count and go into negative values. Is that possible?

Why not crating an additional table with the 2 members package and days? Then you can use a left join to get the diff-value. Advantage: For new packages only a new record is needed, but not code edits.
